Iterating an object array inside object array
Iam trying to solve a project card game.There is a method is called decideWinner()that should find the sum of hearts in player1,player2.Winner is who has the bigger sum of hearts.The symbols for hearts is "#".
I have a question about how to get the value of object spesific class.
@Override
public void decideWinner(Object p1ayer1, Object player2) {
    int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
     Object[] p1 = new Object[5];
     Object[] p2 = new Object[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        
        p1[i] = new Card();
        p1[i] = p1ayer1;
        
        
        if (p1[i].toString().substring(0, 1).equals("#")) {
            sum1++;
            
        }
        p2[i] = new Card();
        p2[i] = player2;
        

        if (p2[i].toString().substring(0, 1).equals("#")) {
            sum2++;
            
        }
    }

   

} 

I want to access the value of object that contains a string like "#5".For some reason this line doesn't access the value.
p1[i].toString().substring(0, 1).equals("#"))

I'm not sure if it is necessary the objects of array p1,p2 and instead of that i used the object player 1.For example :
 player1.toString().substring(0, 1).equals("#")) 


Your code doesn't make a lot of sense: p1[i] = new Card();p1[i] = p1ayer1; Why would you overwrite a Card object with plain Object? You also need to state your GOAL
and not the steps. And describe what the symbols are

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When the players are objects of a specific type, declare the method parameters to be of that type, so you can access specific members of the player class. Create the necessary members, e.g. methods to ask for the intended conditions, if they do not exist. Don’t try to apply magic through the toString() method (even that method needs to be implemented in the player class to do the intended thing). Besides that, as others mentioned, the code makes no sense. You are doing exactly the same thing, five times.

When removing everything that has no effect, your code is basically doing: int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0; if(p1ayer1.toString().startsWith("#")) { sum1 = 5; } if(player2.toString().startsWith("#")) { sum2 = 5; }

Why Object player instead of Player player? Why not Card[] instead of Object[]? You make things much harder by not using the appropriate interfaces for your code, whatever they may be. Rather than turning every object in the world into a string and doing string processing everywhere, it's a lot easier to work with the objects directly like card.isSpade() or card.getValue(). These types/method names are made up, but you can easily make them yourself and implement them, then use them just like I proposed. Or you can use your own design. But processing strings is caveman-esque in comp

@Rogue I use objects player1,player2 as arguments in my method that they have been returned by another method ex.dealToplayers() which picks ramdomly five elements from deck class returning an object array which contains player1,player2.I don't know if it makes sense!!And then i use them as parameters in method decideWinner().It is a spesific  syntax of the project i should follow i suppose like this one:  void decideWinner(Object player1, Object player2) dealing with objects instead Card[]

@Evita this might have to be a separate exercise, but try replacing your usage of Object and Object[] throughout the code with the appropriate interfaces. You might then makesomething like Player#draw(Card[] deck, int num), which would grab num cards for that player (storing them in the Player class). From there you might start to realize that working with arrays in Java kinda sucks, and there are collections (like List<Card> or Set<Card>) that can make your life easier (e.g. Player#draw could simply remove cards from the deck at that point!).

Use Card[] and put a toString() method on Card, or better yet, add a getSuit() method to Card.

Please do not use Object unless you really have to!
You should create a few classes that represent various objects for a game of Hearts: Rank/Suit, Card, Deck, and Player.
A card's value can be calculated like so:
int getValue() {
    if (suit == Suit.HEARTS) return 1;
    if (suit == Suit.SPADES && rank == Rank.QUEEN) return 13;
    return 0;
}

A player's score could be calculated like so:
int getScore() {
    return hand.stream().mapToInt(Card::getValue).sum();
}

And determining the winner can be accomplished via:
void determineWinner() {
    players.stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Player::getScore))
            .ifPresent(winner -> System.out.printf("%nWinner: %s%n", winner));
}

Here is a modified version of my Poker application:
package org.example.cards;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Hearts {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HeartsGame game = new HeartsGame();

        List.of("Bob", "Alice", "Charlie", "David")
                .forEach(name -> game.addPlayer(new Player(name)));

        game.deal();
        game.showHands();
        game.determineWinner();
    }

    static class HeartsGame {
        private static final int NUM_CARDS = 13;

        final List<Player> players;
        final Deck deck;

        HeartsGame() {
            deck = new Deck();
            players = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        void addPlayer(Player player) {
            players.add(player);
        }

        void deal() {
            deck.shuffle();
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CARDS; i++) {
                for (Player player : players) {
                    player.hand.add(deck.draw());
                }
            }
        }

        void showHands() {
            players.forEach(player -> {
                player.sortHand();
                System.out.println(player);
            });
        }

        void determineWinner() {
            players.stream()
                    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Player::getScore))
                    .ifPresent(winner -> System.out.printf("%nWinner: %s%n", winner));
        }
    }

    static class Player {
        final String name;
        final List<Card> hand;

        Player(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            hand = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        int getScore() {
            return hand.stream()
                    .mapToInt(Card::getValue)
                    .sum();
        }

        void sortHand() {
            hand.sort(Comparator.comparing(Card::getSuit).thenComparing(Card::getRank));
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s: %s (%d)", name, hand, getScore());
        }
    }

    static class Deck {
        final List<Card> cards;

        Deck() {
            cards = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
                for (Rank rank : Rank.values()) {
                    cards.add(new Card(suit, rank));
                }
            }
        }

        void shuffle() {
            final Random rand = new Random();
            for (int currIndex = cards.size() - 1; currIndex > 0; currIndex--) {
                int randIndex = rand.nextInt(currIndex + 1);
                Card randCard = cards.get(randIndex);
                cards.set(randIndex, cards.get(currIndex));
                cards.set(currIndex, randCard);
            }
        }

        Card draw() {
            return cards.remove(cards.size() - 1);
        }
    }

    static class Card {
        final Suit suit;
        final Rank rank;

        Suit getSuit() {
            return suit;
        }

        Rank getRank() {
            return rank;
        }

        Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) {
            this.suit = suit;
            this.rank = rank;
        }

        int getValue() {
            if (suit == Suit.HEARTS) return 1;
            if (suit == Suit.SPADES && rank == Rank.QUEEN) return 13;
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s%s", rank.getSymbol(), suit.getSymbol());
        }
    }

    enum Suit {
        HEARTS("♥"),
        DIAMONDS("♦"),
        CLUBS("♣"),
        SPADES("♠");

        final String symbol;

        String getSymbol() {
            return symbol;
        }

        Suit(String symbol) {
            this.symbol = symbol;
        }
    }

    enum Rank {
        TWO("2"),
        THREE("3"),
        FOUR("4"),
        FIVE("5"),
        SIX("6"),
        SEVEN("7"),
        EIGHT("8"),
        NINE("9"),
        TEN("T"),
        JACK("J"),
        QUEEN("Q"),
        KING("K"),
        ACE("A");

        final String symbol;

        String getSymbol() {
            return symbol;
        }

        Rank(String symbol) {
            this.symbol = symbol;
        }
    }
}

Output:
Bob: [T♥, K♥, 4♦, 7♦, K♦, 2♣, K♣, 3♠, 4♠, 6♠, 7♠, T♠, A♠] (2)
Alice: [2♥, 4♥, 7♥, 8♥, 9♥, 3♦, A♦, 5♣, 7♣, 9♣, T♣, A♣, K♠] (5)
Charlie: [6♥, Q♥, A♥, 9♦, T♦, J♦, Q♦, 4♣, 8♣, J♣, Q♣, 5♠, Q♠] (16)
David: [3♥, 5♥, J♥, 2♦, 5♦, 6♦, 8♦, 3♣, 6♣, 2♠, 8♠, 9♠, J♠] (3)

Winner: Charlie: [6♥, Q♥, A♥, 9♦, T♦, J♦, Q♦, 4♣, 8♣, J♣, Q♣, 5♠, Q♠] (16)

